# Cannot make a simple find element with a cssSelector using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to do a click on a button, in various manners without success. Every time i tried, i always get this stack error

```
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:441)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:426)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
    at $Proxy1.findElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The button i want to click has this html

```
<div id="" class="tile bg-blue shipping" style="" shippingid="100">
    <div class="tile-body text-center">
        <h4 class="code">ShippingOrder</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

This are some of the commands I've used:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4[class='code'][value='ShippingOrder']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(), 'ShippingOrder')]");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".bg-blue.shipping[shippingid=\"100\"]")).click();
```

Comment: Is this reproduceable in different browsers?

Comment: I'm testing with chromedriver, tried it on Firefox and it does not work too.

Comment: does your class "code"is unique? then you can use method , by.classname.

Comment: the problem was that I needed to wait for the button to be built by javascript, which is more than 100ms, that's why the webdriver didn't get it. I first tried a 100ms sleep it didn't work, after I tried 1s, and it got through

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was the amount of time javascript takes to build the button, so the html still did not exist at the time I was searching for it.
Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML snippet there is no element, that has a class `code` AND an attribute `value` with a value `ShippingOrder`. `ShippingOrder` is the text content of that element.
To start with try this:

```
print driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".code")).getText();
```

Comment: it didn't print anything, then I tried to print the body and it didn't print the button. I realized that I needed to wait for the javascript to build the button, that's why it didn't found it. so it kind of helped me to printit

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h4[class='code']")).click();

Comment: Do not put just code , please explain that why your answer is that code and why it will work succesfully. Also mentioned what mistake questioner did and how you are making correct that?